# How to Zoom and get latitude and longitude from mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) in Google Map (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

I was setting `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and I am successfully getting my current location but...

1. Not able to zoom to that position.
2. Not able to get lat and lng from that position

From getting latitude and longitude I am using below code but it gives me `null`.  I am calling below method  from `onMapReady(Google Map)` and passing google map object.

```
private void goToCurrentLocation(GoogleMap map) {
        Log.d("Tag", "inside");

        Location loc = map.getMyLocation();
        if (loc != null) {
            LatLng point = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
            Log.d("Tag=", "latlng=" + point);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15));
        }

    }
```

Is there any alternative to getting latitude and longitude as `getMyLocation` deprecated?

Comment: Follow following tutorial: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-google-maps-tutorial-google-maps-android-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use link provided in the answer to get current location and then zoom over that location using below code:

```
latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android